# how to solve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities' in airflow 2.3.3?

Tags: linux, centos7, airflow-2.x, data-integration

I have installed new utilities-package but also the issue is not solved and could not get any new solution from the web.
error:

```
Broken DAG: [/data/airflow/dags/DA.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/data/airflow/dags/DA.py", line 28, in <module>
    from utilities.utilities import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Solved it. changed the operator in python that was depreciated in airflow2